# Prestashop 1.7 - Error 503 - Service Unavailable

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

We started to have an issue on our prestashop backoffice. First, everything was super slow and now it isn´t even possible to access administration because of error 503.

I tried to delete the cache, checked all resources in cpanel (everything good). I found something in error_log, but have no idea if this can be cause by this.

`[04-Feb-2023 23:03:03 US/Central] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid resource type: array in /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php:337`

//UPDATED:

`Stack trace: #0 /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Request.php(57): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor(Array)`

`#1 /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/src/Api/GenericClient.php(178): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request->__construct('POST', Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri), Array, Array)`

`#2 /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/src/Api/EventBusProxyClient.php(138): PrestaShop\Module\PsEventbus\Api\GenericClient->post(Array)`

`#3 /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/src/Service/ProxyService.php(76): PrestaShop\Module\PsEventbus\Api\EventBusProxyClient->uploadDelete('repeat:9740b8b0...', '{"collection":"...')`

`#4 /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/src/Service/DeletedObjectsService.php(51): PrestaShop\Module\PsEventbus\Service\ProxyService->delete('repeat:9740b8b0...', Array)`

`#5 /home/plexrgvc/public_html in /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php on line 337`

`[04-Feb-2023 23:03:04 US/Central] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid resource type: array in /home/plexrgvc/public_html/modules/ps_eventbus/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php:337`

I tried to manually disable this module in phpmyadmin, but didn´t work. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: You'll need more details to find out what is causing this issue. The error lies in a vendor file, which means something being passed upstream is incorrect.

Comment: Updated the topic, found more in the error log. Could this be it?